# Select single XML node from document

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm trying to load some values from an XML document returned by a Philips Hue Bridge. Here is an example of the XML I'm trying to parse (example taken from Philips' website):

```
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <URLBase>https://192.168.1.130:80/</URLBase>
    <device>
        <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:Basic:1</deviceType>
        <friendlyName>Philips hue (192.168.1.130)</friendlyName>
        <manufacturer>Royal Philips Electronics</manufacturer><manufacturerURL>https://www.philips.com</manufacturerURL>
        <modelDescription>Philips hue Personal Wireless Lighting</modelDescription>
        <modelName>Philips hue bridge 2012</modelName>
        <modelNumber>929000226503</modelNumber>
        <modelURL>https://www.meethue.com</modelURL>
        <serialNumber>001788102201</serialNumber>
        <UDN>uuid:2f402f80-da50-11e1-9b23-001788102201</UDN>
        <presentationURL>index.html</presentationURL>
        <iconList>
            <icon>
                <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
                <height>48</height>
                <width>48</width>
                <depth>24</depth>
                <url>hue_logo_0.png</url>
            </icon>
            <icon>
                <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
                <height>120</height>
                <width>120</width>
                <depth>24</depth>
                <url>hue_logo_3.png</url>
            </icon>
        </iconList>
    </device>
</root>
```

I've looked at several examples online and tried various paths, but the result is always null. I've put multiple examples in comments to show you some of the things I've tried.

```
var xml = webClient.DownloadString($"http://{bridge.internalipaddress.ToString()}/description.xml");
XmlDocument bridgeDetails = new XmlDocument();
bridgeDetails.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNode root = bridgeDetails.DocumentElement;
var friendlyName = bridgeDetails.SelectSingleNode("//device/friendlyName");
//var friendlyName = bridgeDetails.SelectSingleNode("/device/friendlyName");
//var friendlyName = bridgeDetails.SelectSingleNode("device/friendlyName");
//var friendlyName = bridgeDetails.SelectSingleNode("descendant::device/friendlyName");
//var friendlyName = root.SelectSingleNode("//device/friendlyName");
//var friendlyName = root.SelectSingleNode("/device/friendlyName");
//var friendlyName = root.SelectSingleNode("device/friendlyName");
//var friendlyName = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::device/friendlyName");
//I've also tried adding .Value.ToString() at the end of some of these, but that just caused a null reference exception
```

EDIT:

I've worked out that I'm missing the namespace. But I'm not sure how as there is no URL to the namespace. E.g.

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(bridgeDetails.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("upnp", "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0");

XmlNode root = bridgeDetails.DocumentElement;
var friendlyName = bridgeDetails.SelectSingleNode("//upnp:device/friendlyName");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your XML is in a namespace created on your root element by `xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0"`. You have to respect that in your XPath expression, or else it will return `null`. So read about namespaces in C# and how to use them in XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I've just worked that out, but not sure how to do it. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution after adding the namespace was close.
Now use the following XPath-1.0 expression, because *all* children or `<root>` are in this namespace:

```
//upnp:device/upnp:friendlyName
```

In complete, this should look like

```
var friendlyName = bridgeDetails.SelectSingleNode("//upnp:device/upnp:friendlyName", nsmgr);
```

and return you the value

> Philips hue (192.168.1.130)

---

Relating to your statement

> But I'm not sure how as there is no URL to the namespace.

The namespace URI does not have to be a valid URL. It just has to be a unique string (in your *"name"-space*) and it doesn't have to point to a retrievable file. That's not neccessary.

Comment: Thank you that works, although I don't fully understand why the `upnp:` is needed before each element name. I get that they are all within that namespace, but as you're referring to a child element of one which you've already specified is in that namespace (I.e. `upnp:device`) why is it still needed?

Comment: The namespace is inherited by all children after its definition. If a new default namespace is defined on one of the children, this one would be inherited from there on.